# Which database roles are needed in SQL Server Management Studio to add and execute stored procedures

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

We have added some stored procedures in SQL Server 2012 Management Studio but in our ASP.NET project we can't add them to the Entity Framework, because we can't see them in the list.

It seems to be a problem with the database roles in SQL Server.

Which roles are needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to execute the following query:

```
USE database_name;
GRANT EXECUTE TO [myStoredName];
```

Also check [Grant Permissions on a Stored Procedure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345484.aspx)

Comment: Thank You Rahul! That's it.